# How to access FloatingActionMenu and Floating Action Button in Robotium?

Tags: android, testing, robotium, floating-action-button

```
FloatingActionMenu fmenu=(FloatingActionMenu) solo.getCurrentActivity().findViewById(R.id.fab_menu);
FloatingActionButton fb1=(FloatingActionButton) solo.getCurrentActivity().findViewById(R.id.fab_compose_mail);
```

I want to click on these menus and buttons. 
Please help me with how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a clickOnView().

```
View fab = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.myFloatingActionButton);
solo.clickOnView(fab);
```